# Where the .cpp files are stored on installed Delphi .groupproj file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, group-project

I have a RxLib Tools installed on my Delphi XE. I need to learn more about the RxLib source but I don't know where the .cpp files are stored on installed Delphi .groupproj file..

Anyone here can help me where it were stored?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Surely you could have just used Explorer to search for the files.

Comment: @RobKennedy I've been search using explorer but it still can't be found...

Comment: @Andromeda, you may be confused by the presence of .hpp files - ie, C++ header files.  They are autogenerated by the Delphi compiler, and are C++ headers *for the Delphi units.*  There are no corresponding .cpp files.  To find the implementation, look for the Pascal file with the same name as the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RxLib library is coded in Delphi, not C++, so there's no cpp files involved, just .pas files.

Where the files are located in your disk may vary depending on how you installed the library.

1. If you used an installer and the installer made the IDE library path configuration to let the IDE browse the units source code, you can use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click IDE feature to automatically open the file and inspect its location. To do so, add a component from the library to a form and save it (to let the IDE add all the required units to the uses clause). Locate the file of your interest in the uses clause, hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and you'll see how the unit name is turned into a *hyperlink* when you hover the mouse over it. Click the unit name and the unit will be opened.

   <sub>I use the jedi library in my example, because I don't use rx anymore since it was added to jvcl.</sub>

   [image: ctrl+click]

   Now, you hover the mouse over the page title when this file is active in the IDE, and you get the file name including the full path.

   [image: full path]

Answer (score 1):

The only C++ files I see in that project are for [the C++ Builder demo](http://rxlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rxlib/trunk/Demos/CBUILDER/). It's otherwise a Delphi project with Delphi code.